# Backgrounds aleatórios em cada carregamento de pagina em paginas estáticas

Tags: javascript, css, jekyll

Estou criando um site/blog com o jekyll, e eu crieri um banner.html e inclui ele no layout default, porem eu queria que ao carregar a pagina toda hora fosse um background diferente nesse banner e estou tentando fazer isso por javascript mas ainda não tive sucesso, o código que crie foi esse:

```
function aplicarBGAleatorio() {
var numeroBG = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

if ($("#bannerMain").length) {
    alert(backgroundAleatorio(numeroBG));
    $("#bannerMain").css({ 'background-image': 'url("../../assets/Imagens/' + backgroundAleatorio(numeroBG) + '");' });
}

if ($("#bannerSecondary").length) {
    alert(backgroundAleatorio(numeroBG));
    $("#bannerSecondary").css({ 'background-image': 'url("../../assets/Imagens/' + backgroundAleatorio(numeroBG) + '");' });
}
}

function backgroundAleatorio(x) {
switch (x) {
    case 0:
        return "background0.jpg";
        break;
    case 1:
        return "background1.jpg";
        break;
    case 2:
        return "background2.jpg";
        break;
    case 3:
        return "background3.jpg";
        break;
    case 4:
        return "background4.jpg";
        break;
}
}

$(document).ready(function () {

aplicarBGAleatorio();
```

com esse código do jeito que está, os dois alerts dentro dos ifs funcionam, mas os backgrounds não aparecem, e não da erro no console.

```
<section id="bannerMain" data-speed="3">
<main>
    <h1>{% if page.title %}{{ page.title | escape }}{% else %}{{ site.title | escape }}{% endif %}</h1>
    <hr>
    <h2>{% if page.desc %}{{ page.desc | escape }}{% else %}{{ site.slogan | escape }}{% endif %}</h2>
    <button>{ Ver mais }</button>
</main>
```

```
section#bannerMain {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 0;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
padding-top: 75px;
```

}

Comment: Já olhou no inspetor do navegador qual é o valor da propriedade que foi carregada? Aliás, "não aparecem" é o fundo ficar branco, sem imagem alguma?

Comment: O navegador aprensenta algum erro? se sim qual?

Comment: Disponibilize o html,css para que possamos analisar todo o contexto..

Comment: Disponibilize o html e o css

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss no inspetor do chrome não da indícios de que foi aplicado algum background-image, o background fica branco, sem imagem sem erro no console e sem nada de diferente no inspetor

Comment: O path da `URL` das imagens está incorreto.

Comment: @FabianoLothor mas eu fiz alguns testes deixando o javascript de lado e colocando essa mesma url `url("../../assets/Imagens/background0.jpg");` no css ele aparece o background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifique as linhas abaixo:

`Ao invés de fazer:`

```
$("#bannerMain").css({ 'background-image': 'url("../../assets/Imagens/' + backgroundAleatorio(numeroBG) + '");' });


$("#bannerSecondary").css({ 'background-image': 'url("../../assets/Imagens/' + backgroundAleatorio(numeroBG) + '");' });
```

`Faça:`

```
$('#bannerMain').css('background-image', 'url("../../assets/Imagens/' + backgroundAleatorio(numeroBG) + '")');

$('#bannerSecondary').css('background-image', 'url("../../assets/Imagens/' + backgroundAleatorio(numeroBG) + '")');
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado @FabianoLothor